# mysql query combine table from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

My mysql table looks like this:

```
word1  word2  count
a      c      1
a      d      2
a      e      3
a      f      4
b      c      5
b      d      6
b      g      7
b      h      8
```

"a" and "b" are user inputs - select * from table where word1='a' or word1='b' - gets ~10000 rows

I need a query to get:
word1 is column for intput "a"

word1_ is column for input "b"

word2 and word2_ are the same column so one of them can be ignored

i need to combine table below from table above.
for example this query:

```
select 
  t1.word1, t1.word2, t1.count, 
  t2.word1 as word1_, t2.word2 as word2_, t2.count as count_
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.word2 = t2.word2
where t1.word1 = 'a' and t2.word1 = 'b'
```

produces

```
word1   word2   count   word1_  word2_  count_  
a       c       1       b       c       5
a       d       2       b       d       6
```

I need to get count=0 where word2 is not found.

```
word1  word2  count  word1_  word2_  count_
a      c      1      b       c       5
a      d      2      b       d       6
a      e      3      b       e       0
a      f      4      b       f       0
a      g      0      b       g       7
a      h      0      b       h       8
```

P.S. the table has 11million rows index is set on `word1`

P.P.S. Provided answer does work but it took 20 sec to complete the query. I will need to do this programmatically by myself to get better performance.

Comment: so u mean **word1_, word2_ and count_** are different columns??  so what they are?  Please make it more clear what these names are??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a FULL OUTER JOIN... which doesn't exist in mysql.

You can do it this way.

```
select 
      t1.word1, t1.word2, t1.count, 
      coalesce(t2.word1, 'b') as word1_, t1.word2 as word2_, coalesce(t2.count, 0) as count_
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t1.word2 = t2.word2 and t2.word1 = 'b'
where t1.word1 = 'a' 
union
select 
      coalesce(t2.word1, 'a'), t1.word2 , coalesce(t2.count, 0),
      t1.word1 as word1_, t1.word2 as word2_, t1.count

from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t1.word2 = t2.word2 and t2.word1='a'
where t1.word1 = 'b'
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e96/50)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need any UNION or OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT 'a' word1
     , b.word2
     , max(CASE word1 WHEN 'a' THEN count ELSE 0 END) count
     , 'b' _word1
     , b.word2 _word2
     , max(CASE word1 WHEN 'b' THEN count ELSE 0 END) _count
FROM   words a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT word2
                   FROM   words
                   WHERE  word1 IN ('a', 'b')) b ON a.word2 = b.word2
GROUP BY b.word2
ORDER BY b.word2
```

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/1047a/5)
In the demo I added a row where word1 is neither 'a' or 'b', if you want every value of word2 regardless the value of word1 just strip the WHERE condition of the subquery

Comment: This works but is slower than Raphaël Althaus answer

Comment: I tried it on my own system. Raphaël Althaus answer took 20 sec (which is too slow for me). Your answer took more than few mins so I had to let it go and restart mysql. But thank you for your efforts anyway!